# .bat - insert text before a period

Tags: batch-file

I have a .bat that I use to quickly query basic information from servers. After it gets the FQDN from DNS, I need to insert a "-r" (minus quotes) after the servername, but before the ".domain.com". The area that it will be added to the script is below -

```
for /f "delims=[] tokens=2" %%b in ('ping %servername% -n 1 ^| findstr "["') do (set thisip=%%b)
for /f "tokens=2" %%a in ('nslookup %thisip% ^| find /i "Name: "') do (set fqdnstat=%%a)
```

so how can I take the FQDN, which is set to fqdnstat, and modify it from  - 
server.domain.com
to server-r.domain.com ?

Edit - I guess I didn't really explain very well. I just need to insert text into a line of text, before a period. I need to take the following name: server.domain.com and edit it to read server-r.domain.com, using a command. The rest of the script above is context for the issue. The fqdnstat is the variable that I use to for the Fully Qualified Domain Name.

Comment: You also need to actually ask a question.

Comment: I apologize. I rephrased to ask a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid I don't really understand your concern, but this Batch file may help you:

```
@echo off

set fqdnstat=server.domain.com
echo Before: "%fqdnstat%"
for /F "tokens=1* delims=." %%a in ("%fqdnstat%") do set "fqdnstat=%%a-r.%%b"
echo After:  "%fqdnstat%"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
set servername=%servername:.domain.com=-r.domain.com%
```

Presumably above the two lines you've put, but I'm not sure what the goal is, so maybe not.